# LINQ version of SQL View?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-view

Okay, here's a dumb question.

As I understand it, a SQL View is a virtual table based on the result-set of a SQL query.

From my limited knowledge of a SQL View, I'm assuming that a result set that I get from a LINQ statement is the same thing as a SQL View.

Am I mistaken?

The reason I'm asking is that I have a program that is using a `foreach` loop to read over a result-set from a LINQ query, row by row.  A co-worker said I should use a pre-built SQL View to speed up the program.  Not being familiar with SQL Views, I'm not sure how it would help me, based on my limited knowledge.

Comment: In code, they are functionally the same. SQL Views could be faster, it depends on your use case

Comment: Perhaps that is why my co-worker mentioned using a SQL View.  I'm checking certain criteria within the `foreach` on each record, row by row.  Perhaps he meant that I could use a view to pare down the results set, thereby discarding records that don't meet my criteria.  But, I could probably do that on the original result-set from the LINQ statement.  I could just pare down the results, weeding out records I don't need and then iterate over the remaining results.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, if you apply a useful Where and `Select new` on the original LINQ statement you will be essentially doing the same as if you were making a SQL view. For the most part, SQL should be able to run an arbitrary query (from LINQ) with very comparable performance to SQL view, but there will be cases where a SQL view will be better optimized.

Comment: The SQL View *can* benefit from database internal ways of storing the data. Depending on the size of your table this *can* give you better performance. But if you query some times through LINQ, every modern database will do those optimizations on its own. So in the end, you will probably not get that much of an effect. At least you should get the same data in about the same time either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look to SQL views as a result set, that may combine the values of multiple tables (by joining, using sub-select's etc.). If you query a SQL view, you get better performance.

Linq 2 SQL returns you set of data and does a mapping to an object, so you get IList.

Linq works with so called IQueryable interface. The benefit is that IQueryable is executed when you hit iq.List(), iq.Array() method on the IQueryable expression.

I actually used it in one of my project in a special way:
- created the desired IQueryable query
- then depending on the use-case I've executed iq.Count() or iq.List() on it. Since I could avoid calint iq.List() (and since I mostly needed only to know the count) I got perf. increase - and I didn't had to modify existing code considerably.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I'll mark the answer as soon as the timer is up.